# Git: best flow for going back and changing history

Tags: git

Let me preface this by saying this is an unusual git flow. I am writing a tutorial with a long readme that gives code examples along the way.

A user could checkout an early commit and see the state of the project I am building at that point, follow the tutorial more, checkout the next commit, etc.

I would really like to do this with git but I have a problem because if I go back and want to change something in the beginning of the tutorial (typos or methods) then I need to go back and change the history which has a lot of commits that come after it.

Is there an easy way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: If you rewrite one or more of those earlier commits, a user who previously checked out the branch would have to delete his local copy of the branch and check it out again.  Is this an acceptable workflow to you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think the post isn't about "How do I make this part of a workflow", it's "How do I construct a specific git history for the sake of my one-off tutorial".

Comment: @AndrewShepherd No, I disagree.  The OP strongly implies that it wants to go back and change history to fix typos etc. while other users are currently working with a version of the branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think that is acceptable...If they did a git pull on the origin, would it rewrite their local copy?

Comment: It's worse than that.  If you rewrite history, they would have to kill their current local branch and check it out again.  Or reset hard to the latest remote HEAD.  Either way, it would be intrusive.

Comment: hmm I see, do you know of any better way to accomplish the end result like I said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual workaround is to make a branch per step you want your user to follow.

By default, the branches would point to your existing commits in `master`.

```
 x--x--x--x--x--x--x (master)
    |        |
  (step1)   (step2)
```

But should you need to fix one of those commits, instead of re-writing said commit (changing the history/SHA1 of all other subsequent commits), you would checkout that branch, make a new commit there.

```
 x--x--x--x--x--x--x (master)
    |        |
    X       (step2)
 (step1)
```

Any user using that branch would just have to do a git pull to get the updated version of that step.

You can then [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) that new commit to `master` (and to the other branches after this one), and go on.
I don't think merges are needed (in order to not get an history graph needlessly complex)

Comment: this seems like a good idea, but what if you made a commit in step 1 (to fix or update something) after the step 2 branch was created. How do you go about propogating the change to step 2 since it builds off of step 1?

Comment: @deltaskelta you can cherry-pick to other branches as well your new commit.

Comment: ah ok I didnt know about cherry picking. this looks like exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @deltaskelta Yes, I have edited the answer to add the link to the cherry-pick command.

Comment: I have been playing around with a simple example and it seems that I will have to `cherry-pick` and fix conflicts (if there are conflicts) for every branch or chapter in the tutorial for every change. So if I have 10 branches and I want to change something in the initial commit, I should run cherry-pick 10 times?

Comment: @deltaskelta yes, but if your branch names follow a simple naming convention, it can be scripted easily enough. If you fix something in step3, you have to cherry-pick in step4, 5, 6... not step2 and 1.